# beamer: convenient ways to make backup slides

Tags: beamer

When there are some backup slides in beamer, is there a convenient way to make quick links to the back up slides and come back quickly, instead of adding links two both slides?

Comment: Some viewers (like acrobat) make it easy to go back to where you were.

Comment: @Mark Right, but not in all cases you have control of what software to use...